# PM2(node) Sending a message to a cluster from the commandline

Tags: node.js, linux, pm2

So I have a process managed with `PM2` that's made in `Nodejs` which is pretty typical. However looking through documentation it looks like it's possible to send messages to process launched in cluster mode.

The problem is that the documentation is programmatic, with no hints on how to call that from the command line other than passing a `sigusr2` to the application. If I could pass a message with `sigusr2` that'd also solve my problem, but just passing a message to the cluster is useful enough if I could find that.

So is there a way to pass a message to a cluster of processes managed by `PM2` so I can handle it with the `process.on('message', ()=>{})` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be available on PM2 2.1.6!

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2509

Official documentation: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-actions/

Comment: When this functionality is up and available I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: Gimme some time to check that is production ready enough :) btw this is already available for testing on development branch:
$ npm install Unitech/pm2#development -g
$ pm2 update

Looking forward potential feedbacks!

Comment: Will test and feedback